# What is wrong with my JWT signing implementation

Tags: hash, jwt, rsa

I am trying to understand JWT better by implementing my own signing functions that take in the payload and header and output a signature, however I am running into issues when I try and verify my results using proven tools. Below is my implementation, any help would be appreciated.

```js
const createSignatureUsingBaseLibrary = (input: string) => {
  const hash = crypto.createHash("sha256");
  hash.write(input);
  const hashedM = hash.digest();
  const encryptedM = crypto
    .privateEncrypt(
      {
        key: privateKey,
        padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING,
      },
      hashedM
    )
    .toString("base64");

  return encryptedM;
};
```

I'm really at a loss for what could be the issue, but I think it has to something to do with the way in which I am encoding the message or possibly with the encryption options being different to the 'JWT standard';

Answer (score 0):

[`crypto.privateEncrypt()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_privateencrypt_privatekey_buffer) is a low level function that implicitly neither hashes nor, in the case of PKCS#1 v1.5 padding (RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5), sets the digest ID. A typical use case would be when only the hash of the data is available rather than the actual data.

In the posted code the digest ID is not set, which is why the generated signature is not PKCS#1 v1.5 compliant and verification fails.

For a PKCS#1 v1.5 compliant signature, the digest ID (for SHA256) must be set as follows:

```
const digestID = Buffer.from('3031300d060960864801650304020105000420', 'hex');
const hashedM = Buffer.concat([digestID, hash.digest()]);
```

PKCS#1 v1.5 padding is described in detail in [RFC8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017).

---

Also, JWTs apply Base64url and not Base64 encoding, i.e. the following additional transformation is required:

```
return encryptedM.toString('base64').replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/=/g, "");
```

Of course, you can also use a library that supports Base64url.

---

However, since according to the posted code the data is available (and not just the hash), *crypto*'s standard functions for creating a signature can be applied, implicitly hashing and setting the digest ID, which makes it much easier to use, namely [`sign.sign()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_sign_sign_privatekey_outputencoding) (since v0.1.92):

```
const sign = crypto.createSign('SHA256');
sign.update(Buffer.from(input, 'utf8'));
const signatureB64 = sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64');
```

or [`crypto.sign()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_sign_algorithm_data_key_callback) (since v12.0.0):

```
const signatureB64 = crypto.sign('sha256', Buffer.from(input, 'utf8'), privateKey);
```

Both variants apply PKCS#1 v1.5 padding by default.